# How can I set permission for seperate request methods in DRF ModelViewSet?

Tags: python, django, api, http, django-rest-framework

I'm fairly new to Django and Django Rest Framework and I can't figure out why my code isn't working.
I have a Biz model that has a few fields:

```
class Biz(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
```

which I serializer using ModelSerializer:

```
class BizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Biz
        fields = "__all__"
```

And I use ModelViewSet to have an endpoint for it:

```
class BizViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Biz.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = [HasGroupPermission]
    required_groups = {
        "GET": ["__all__"],
        "POST": ["member", "biz_post"],
        "PUT": ["member", "biz_edit"],
        "PATCH": ["member", "biz_edit"],
    }

    serializer_class = BizSerializer
```

You probably noticed `HasGroupPermission`. It is a custom permission I made to confirm the requesting user is in required group(s) the code is:

```
def is_in_group(user, group_name):
    """
    Takes a user and a group name, and returns `True` if the user is in that group.
    """
    try:
        return Group.objects.get(name=group_name).user_set.filter(id=user.id).exists()
    except Group.DoesNotExist:
        return None


class HasGroupPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Ensure user is in required groups.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # Get a mapping of methods -> required group.
        required_groups_mapping = getattr(view, "required_groups", {})

        # Determine the required groups for this particular request method.
        required_groups = required_groups_mapping.get(request.method, [])

        # Return True if the user has all the required groups or is staff.
        return all(
            [
                is_in_group(request.user, group_name)
                if group_name != "__all__"
                else True
                for group_name in required_groups
            ]
        ) or (request.user and request.user.is_staff)
```

However, when I make a GET request, the permission function works like it's supposed to and allows everyone to make the request, and when i make a POST request, the permission function also works perfectly (if user isn't in both "member" and "biz_post" groups the request is denied). 
The problem arises when I try other methods such as PUT, PATCH, and DELETE. **Why is this issue happening?** Half the methods work and the other half (sorta) don't. My knowledge in DRF is limited at the moment, and I can't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: That's for sure FULL CODE of your viewset ?

Comment: @monio Yes, for my Biz viewset that's all, except for a few imports and other models' viewsets which i suppose are irrelevant to BizViewSet (?).

Comment: I suggest to debug your HasGroupPermission.has_permission method and ensure that on "PUT" method, required_groups and request.method variable are correct (you can debug or just print there those informations). Another option is to use view.action variable instead of request.method for mapping. DRF by default maps respectively GET (on list), POST, GET (on detail), PUT, DELETE methods to view.action named list, create, retrieve, update, delete.

Comment: @monio The function is working perfectly with POST and GET request permissions. I printed the function and debugged it as well. Nothing wrong there in my eyes. It queries the group id and checks if the user is in that group. If user isn't in post group only GET is allowed. However, all PUT, PATCH, and DELETE requests are denied regardless of specified group requirements.

Comment: You need to debug your app, maybe you dont send authentication token with PUT, PATCH and DELETE. Sorry but i think problem is somewhere else, it should work. I can connect with you somehow and try to help you (maybe access to git repo).

Comment: @monio You're right actually. I made a really rookie mistake. The problem was I didn't make the PATCH request correctly. I will answer this question to close the thread. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my problem which I found very silly. My BizViewSet is actually a ViewSet and I didn't realize that I have to make PATCH, PUT, and DELETE requests to the object link (as in localhost:8000/api/biz/$id). Since my User serializer isn't a ViewSet I thought the patch method works the same way which was I pass a primary key in JSON along with the data I wanted to patch but ViewSets are different and I didn't know that. Silly.

Comment: Not my proudest moment but it might be someone else's problem somewhere in future as a lot of people will be newbies like myself in this discourse.

Answer (score -2):

Hi you can use DjangoModelPermissions instead of HasGroupPermission

(at the first you must import it)

```
from rest_framework.permissions import DjangoModelPermissions
```

This permission check that user have permission for PUT, POST and DELETE

All user have GET permission

You must set permission for user in admin or set permission for group of user

I hope it helps you

Comment: The problem still remains the same. It properly functinos for GET and POST request, but other methods are simply not allowed regardless of group permission, user permission, superuser status and/or is_staff status.
EDIT: although I think this method is much better and I will have a cleaner code I guess.

Comment: in DjangoModelPermissions for PUT DELETE and PATCH check that user have a permission

Comment: I test for you and it works very well! if user of a group don't have a permission for delete or put or path. user can't do that.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts!
The problem must be something else, then. I will tweak my code a bit to see if anything changes.

Comment: if the answer is true plz accept the answer. thanks

Answer (score -2):

`has_permission` method not provide `object-level` permission and `PUT` and `PATCH` need `object-level` permission.

You must create `object-level` permissions, **that are only run against operations that affect a particular object instance** by using `has_object_permission` method of `permissions.BasePermission` class.

**See this [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples).**

*Hope it helped.*

Comment: has_permission method is ALWAYS called on viewset initial method. It doesn't matter that you will use has_object_permission (unless you need access to object - but not in this situation)